# Omit “.DS_Store” from “ls -a” results

Tags: terminal

MacOS puts “.DS_Store” files in directories. How do you omit them from all “ls -a” results?

Comment: pipe it with `grep -v ".DS_Store"' ?

Answer (score 4):

`ls -a` specifically tells `ls` to list *all* files/directories and especially those starting with `.`, there is no direct way to suppress them. Of course there is always

```
ls -a | fgrep -v .DS_Store
```

but this may be rather cumbersome.

Comment: `ls -a | fgrep -v .DS_Store | column` to recreate the default output